# IE crashes while printing RDLC report

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I am trying to print an RDLC report from a client pc on IE9 it works fine with Chrome and Firefox but it crashes on IE9

The error that i get is

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   iexplore.exe
Application Version:    9.0.8112.16457
Application Timestamp:  50a2f9e3
Fault Module Name:  rsclientprint.dll
Fault Module Version:   2009.100.1352.12
Fault Module Timestamp: 4aeb99c7
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   00017c86
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one way to resolve this problem is run your IE in administrator mode.

The other way to resolve it is :-

1) Tool->Internet Option->Security->Local Intranet->Sites->Advanced
2) Enter your site url and click on Add and close.
3) Then click on custom level and enable each element of Active X controls and plugin.

This will work for you.